# Need help on a complex nested IF THEN in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to do a complex `IF` `THEN` statement.  If A, then create text according to parameters.  If B, create text according to different parameters.  And if C, create text according to a new set of parameters.  The language below all works - individually - I'm unable to "fail" and on the first IF to get to the second.  Might anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

```
IF([@[Pre-Post Aug 2019]]="Aug 2019 Month",
IF(AND(W2>=DATEVALUE("07/22/2018"),W2<=DATEVALUE("07/28/2019")),"BA Week 1",IF(AND(W2>=DATEVALUE("07/29/2019"),W2<=DATEVALUE("08/04/2019")),"BA Week 2",IF(AND(W2>=DATEVALUE("08/05/2019"),W2<=DATEVALUE("08/12/2019")),"BA Week 3",IF(AND(W2>=DATEVALUE("08/13/2019"),W2<=DATEVALUE("08/20/2019")),"BA Week 4",IF(AND(W2>=DATEVALUE("08/21/2019"),W2<=DATEVALUE("08/28/2019")),"BA Week 5",
"Something Else")))))))))))))
```

```
IF([@[Pre-Post Aug 2019]]="Pre Aug 2019 Month",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>0,[@[BA:  Day]]<6),"BA Week 2",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>29,[@[BA:  Day]]<32),"BA Week 2",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>5,[@[BA:  Day]]<14),"BA Week 3",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>13,[@[BA:  Day]]<22),"BA Week 4",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>21,[@[BA:  Day]]<30),"BA Week 1",
IF([@[BA:  Day]]>31,"Check It",
"Something Else")))))))))))))
```

```
IF([@[Pre-Post Aug 2019]]="Post Aug 2019 Month",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>28,[@[BA:  Day]]<31),"BA Week 1",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>0,[@[BA:  Day]]<6),"BA Week 1",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>5,[@[BA:  Day]]<13),"BA Week 2",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>12,[@[BA:  Day]]<21),"BA Week 3",
IF(AND([@[BA:  Day]]>20,[@[BA:  Day]]<29),"BA Week 4",
IF([@[BA:  Day]]>31,"Check It",
"Something Else")))))))))))))
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to add some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Think about applying [SWITCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e).

Comment: Are you only interested in `IF Else` or if you want to try some other method,, **will get `Start & End Date` of the `Week` along with `Week Number`**,, please confirm through comments then I post it .

Answer (score 0):

From memory, you can't nest IFs more than 7 levels deep. But that could be a hazy memory of an old version and the limit may be higher now.

Either way, all those bits which are AND(foo>bar, foo

Also note that your number ranges are mutually exclusive so no two of then can be true at the same time. So instead of

```
IF(A, do thing for A, [else]IF(B, ...IF(C,...
```

all nested up, you could do something to keep them independent and not nested, and just concatenate the results, like:

```
IF(A,result for A,"") & IF(B,result for B,"") & IF(C, etc
```

This way is slightly less efficient because they all have to be evaluated, but your sample seems to indicate the tests are pretty trivial, without 'expensive' functions like lookups. So all the expressions are evaluated, and all but one return "" so you just end up with the one you want but you do not use more than one level of nesting at a time, and should be able to put your three parts together.

You could even do the same for your top-level parts since they seem to test the same thing for three different possible options - just take what you have and concatenate them together using an &